# Parsing MIME header with regular expression

Tags: regex, string, email

I need to extract email address from MIME header in 3 particular cases (they are different due to different email servers that deliver the email - it was a single email sent to multiple (3) recipients).

```
1. Received: by oiax69 with SMTP id x69so5491756oia.2 for <myaddr1@mydomain1.biz>; Sun, 31 May 2015 15:39:45 -0700 (PDT)
2. Received: by oiav63 with SMTP id v63so5487624oia.3 for <myaddr2@mydomain2.com>; Sun, 31 May 2015 15:39:46 -0700 (PDT)    
3. Received: by oiav63 with SMTP id v63so5493687oia.0 for <myaddr3@mydomain3.com>; Sun, 31 May 2015 15:39:45 -0700 (PDT)
```

What would be the right regular expression to extract the email address?
Important to note that each one of them is just a piece of a larger string both before and after...

Comment: You will need to be a lot more specific about how to find the email address in the string to get quality answers. Also, what have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Just look between the greater than and less than symbol when an `@` is present I think would suffice. What language is this in?

Comment: chris85 - I cannot do what you suggest the whole string is huge and have many email addresses. I need to focus on this particular piece that is relevant to me...Somebody commented that it is not enough details - the header is to big to paste here...

Answer (score 0):

There are basically only bad reasons to want to do this, but here is a small Python program which attempts to retrieve the email terminus out of the topmost `Received:` header from its standard input.

```
from sys import stdin, exit

collected = []
for line in stdin:
    line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    if line.startswith('Received:'):
        collected.append(line)
    elif line.startswith(' ') or line.startswith('\t'):
        collected.append(line)
    else:
        final = ''.join(collected)
        # XXX FIXME: the search should also work with a tab before "for"
        start = final.find(' for <')
        if start != -1:
            # XXX WARNING: Throws ValueError if '>' not found
            print("%s" % final[start+6:final.index('>', start+6)])
            exit(0)
        else:
            exit(1)
```

One scenario where you might want to do this is with a homegrown buggy email delivery system.  A proper MTA will pass you the message with its envelope, so you know who the recipient is, but an incorrect implementation gives you just the message, and then you try to figure out what was in the lost envelope.  **Don't do this.** Fix the problem, not the symptom.

On a system where the topmost `Received:` header *usually* contains the intended recipient, it will typically be missing if there were multiple local recipients.

So if you have, say, a wildcard inbox, and somebody sends a message `To: you@example.com` you can observe that the final `Received:` header contains `... for <you@example.com>` and so you hope to be able to discover where to deliver the message.  But if the sender had `Bcc: you@example.com, another@example.com` the `Received:` header will usually *not* contain the recipients, and so the proposed "solution" fails for precisely the case where you don't really have any other means to solve it, either.

Tangentially, another complication is that the `Received:` header format is not formally specified.  The spec says that the header needs to exist, and some things it needs to contain, but there is no specific grammar for how to represent this information.  If you are only dealing with a single version of a single MTA in a single configuration, you can write a parser for that particular `Received:` header format, but there is no reliable way to parse them all.  (Exhibit A: the source of [`SpamAssassin/Message/Metadata/Received.pm`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Message/Metadata/Received.pm)!)

Comment: Your question contains very few details, so I have had to assume some things.  Every message will typically contain multiple `Received:` headers -- I assume the newest, topmost header is the one of interest to you.  If that's not the case, you will need to explain your problem in more detail, probably *much* more detail.  The frame of the problem is more important than a dump of the data you are having trouble with.

Comment: In fact those are 3 examples of headers of email send by different server both from POP and Exchange accounts - since I could not find the right regex I ended up doing similar to your suggestion bu in C#.

Comment: Where they are sent from is less interesting, it's the receiving system which generates the `Received:` header, obviously.